# zclip and jquery ajax issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I know its been covered in various topics about being able to use zclip to copy and paste to the clipboard using ajax, but I'm wondering if my issue is something a bit more general with jquery, firefox and ajax requests...

```
$("#generate-report-to-clipboard").zclip({
            path: '/Content/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: function () {
                var options = {
                    async: false, success: function (data) {
                        // now do ajax call for report results
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%= Url.Action("GenerateEmailToClipboard") %>',
                            type: 'POST',
                            async: false,
                            success: function (data, status) {
                                $("#copy-holder").text(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                $("#report-definition-form").ajaxForm(options);
                $("#report-definition-form").submit();

                return $("#copy-holder").text();
            }, afterCopy: function () { alert('something'); }
        });
```

Ok, so the idea is when I click the link, I go and request the data to copy and on success add that data to the clipboard.

This method works fine in IE 8 (strange I know) and Chrome 12 but not in Firefox 4.

The reason I think it might have something to do with the AJAX request is when I remove the AJAX call and set #copy-holder to a value, it copies to the clipboard with no problem.

Please help, I'm going mad!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the number of AJAX calls to be strange in Firefox. I have a pop-up window that allows the user to copy, then go to the next object, open the pop-up and copy. In Chrome, IE, etc the AJAX requests are a single one and therefore the result can be returned, but in Firefox there numerous AJAX requests. One for each pop-up window the user clicked on.

The problem is the actual jquery.jzclip.js file, the 2nd,3rd.. requests are being passed back from this file into the AJAX function like you have. If you use the console(F12) you can see it happening. No solution to this yet, it's pretty damn annoying trying to troubleshoot the js file that was given.